# objective c checking server certificate at asynchronous https request

Tags: objective-c, ssl, asynchronous, https, certificate

I build a iPhone App which uses a ssl server connection. Everything is going well so far. At the moment I have a litte issue with the server certificate.

I downloaded certificate from this server. So I have the certificate in my project explorer.

I am trying to match the certificate from the server with my previous downloaded in the delegate method of the request 
`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {}`

The issue is, that I have totally no idea how to bring the .cer file in the code to check the key.

Answer (score 1):

found perfect sample code here: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/89542-ssl-connection.html

copy - paste - done, works for me. I have no idea why other snipplets so complicated. Only thing is that the local certificate has to be in keychain. But I totally can't see the disadvantage. Maybe someone can tell me the diference.

```
// prompted by SSL connection 
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
if([protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
{NSLog(@"Attempting SSL Connection...");
    return YES;
}

NSLog(@"Cannot connect through SSL");
return NO;}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)theChallenge{   
challenge = theChallenge;

// "trust" related authentication challenge, prompted by SSL connection
if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
{
    //This takes the serverTrust object and checkes it against your keychain
    SecTrustResultType result;
    SecTrustEvaluate(challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust, &result);

    if (result == kSecTrustResultInvalid)
        NSLog(@"SSL Challenge Result: Invalid");
    else if (result == kSecTrustResultProceed)
        NSLog(@"SSL Challenge Result: Proceed");
    else if (result == kSecTrustResultConfirm)
        NSLog(@"SSL Challenge Result: Confirm");
    else if (result == kSecTrustResultDeny)
        NSLog(@"SSL Challenge Result: Deny");
    else if (result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified)
        NSLog(@"SSL Challenge Result: Unspecified");
    else if (result == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure)
        NSLog(@"SSL Challenge Result: Recoverable Trust Failure");
    else if (result == kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure)
        NSLog(@"SSL Challenge Result: Fatal Trust Failure");
    else if (result == kSecTrustResultOtherError)
        NSLog(@"SSL Challenge Result: Other Error");

    if(result == kSecTrustResultProceed || result == kSecTrustResultConfirm || result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified)
    {
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge];
    }
    else
    { 
        [self promptForTrust];
    }
}}
-(void)promptForTrust{//display an error if there are any issues with the connection
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot Verify Server Identity" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxx can't verify the identity of \"%@\". Would you like to continue anyway?", [[Model sharedManager] returnServer]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",@"Details",nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];}-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
    //May need to add a method to add serverTrust to the keychain like Firefox's "Add Exception"

    // if the user decides to trust
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 1)
{// if the user decides not to trust 
    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 2)
{
    // show details of certificate

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I use:

```
NSArray *paths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"p12" inDirectory:nil];
NSMutableArray *idents = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *certPath in paths) {
    CFDataRef certData = (CFDataRef)[[NSData  alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:certPath];
    const void *keys[] = {kSecImportExportPassphrase};
    const void *values[] = {(CFStringRef)kPassword}; // kPassword should be your password
    CFDictionaryRef optsDict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);

    OSStatus status = -1;
    CFArrayRef items = NULL;
    status = SecPKCS12Import(certData, optsDict, &items);
    if (status == 0) { // noErr or errSecSuccess
       CFDictionaryRef item = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
       SecIdentityRef bundleIdent = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(item, kSecImportItemIdentity);
       [idents addObject:(id)bundleIdent];
    }
    if (optsDict) CFRelease(optsDict);
    if (items) CFRelease(items);
    if (certData) CFRelease(certData);
}
```

and voila - you have all `SecIdentityRefs` in `idents` array at your disposal.

---

EDIT:
Here's [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW10) which describes how to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks looks good. But I get a exception `-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2cab00` in the line after setting the password.

Comment: and @all, it doesn't work in simulator at all. I spent a full hour before I recognized that simulator can't decode.

Comment: This code intended get p12 certs, and it works. The reason it fails on you could be anything from wrong file type to encryption issues. BTW, what do you mean by "simulator can't decode"? As a ref you can check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html

Comment: Okay, did it. Problem was xcode suggested to add `__bridge` this caused the error, because I needed `__bridge_retained `. so the line is: `CFDataRef certData = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)[[NSData  alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:certPath];` Now I need to validate the certificate, I know it is in the idents array. But how can I check this? Like in a if statement? thx again

Comment: added link to apple doc, there's evaluation example.

Comment: sorry, but I can't get it to work. I think the basic problem is that by status object is always null. But I have no idea why. In the apple doc is no clue about that. Can please anybody help. thx